# Call to a member function sync() on null (many to many polymorphic laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

hi i have many to many polymorphic Relation

When I use the sync method to insert data in the interface table, I encounter this error. What is the problem?

controller code:

```
$job_create->skills()->sync($request['skill']);
```

job model:

```
   public function skills(){
    $this->morphMany(Skil::class,'skillables');
    }
```

skill model:

```
    public function jobs()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Job::class, 'skillables');
}
```

Comment: Assuming you follow the conventions, you need to drop the "s". it needs to be "skillable"

Answer (score 0):

Relationships should always return the relation.

```
public function skills(){
    return $this->morphMany(Skil::class,'skillables');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that given Skil::class is correct i think it must be Skill::class

```
public function skills(){
 return $this->morphMany(Skill::class,'skillables');
}
```

the error says that $job_create->skills() is null you can test it with dd();

```
dd($job_create->skills()->get());
```

if the problem didn't solved just study the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations